# matching compatible individuals in as few groups possible

Tags: algorithm, sorting, grouping, combinatorics

I am looking for an algorithm to solve the following problem.

Assume I have n individuals. I have a matrix which describes the relationship between all of the individuals. For example individual 1 is compatible with individual 2, this gives a 1 in the matrix. Individual 2 is not compatible with 3, this gives a 0 in the matrix. Incompatibiliy is for example 'they fight when placed together'.

Now, I have to make groups out of these people to put them on busses for travelling. I want all the people in 1 group to be compatible which each other. The only thing which interests me, is minimizing the number of groups. So is there an algorithm to group compatible people in as few groups as possible?

I know this is similar to a lot of existing grouping algorithms (like stable marriage algo and sortalikes), but I cannot find an algorithm to minimize the number of groups.

Anyone having an idea!?

Comment: [Graph coloring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring)

Comment: Seconding David's comment. Each person is a node, and an edge between two people indicate they are incompatible. Color the graph with as few colors as possible; each color is a group.

Comment: @stark : only if the graph is planar. If each people hate each other (complete graph, not planar), they all have to take their own bus.

Comment: Thanks guys, graph coloring algorithm was introduced and results were superb.